# Troubles with running Derby on OS X in Embedded Mode

Tags: derby

I am facing the following problem.
Trying to get Derby DB working in Embedded mode on my Macbook, but getting the following error :

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby

```
Derby log shows :
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.runtime.version=1.8.0_65-b17
user.dir=/Users/a1/Documents/
os.name=Mac OS X
os.arch=x86_64
os.version=10.9.4
derby.system.home=null
Database Class Loader started - derby.database.classpath=''
```

Seems like trouble with environment variable, getting the following when running setEmbeddedCP in my terminal:

```
Error: DERBY_HOME is not set. Please set the DERBY_HOME environment variable
to the location of your Derby installation.
```

The following are contents of bash_profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export DERBY_HOME=$(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/db)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DERBY_HOME` should be set to the location where you downloaded and unzipped the Derby jar files. That is, `$DERBY_HOME/lib/derby.jar` should be the location of your derby.jar file.

Here are some docs: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/getstart/tgssetupenvironment.html

Your actual databases can be located anywhere; they do not have to be located under `DERBY_HOME` (and typically are **not** located there). Commonly, your database is located in a folder that is part of the data files for your application (this is known as the "embedded" configuration), or in a folder that is managed by the Derby Network Server (this is known as the "client/server" configuration).

I recommend working through the entire Derby introduction guide at: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/getstart/index.html

Comment: Thanks, tried this already. In my bash_profile
export DERBY_HOME=$/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/db/lib/derby.jar .
Echo from terminal :
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/db/lib/derby.jar
So now it should be correct, but still getting same error in Eclipse
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:...
I did not explicitly download Derby and unzip Derby jar file, they are bundled with JDK.They do exist in above folder.
Onlinedoc is only about env. variable for Win. / UNIX, no OS X

Comment: OS X is the same as Unix. But, I didn't realize you were talking about Eclipse. That makes a lot of difference. Eclipse has its own way of loading and running JDBC drivers and it is not going to look at the `DERBY_HOME` environment variables; those are only used by the Derby-provided shell scripts.

Comment: Yes, sorry trouble is with the java app from eclipse, can not connect to server.
Or when I try load 
`Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");`
Getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver`

Comment: Update : added derby.jar as referenced library to my project, driver error has gone, now another error I am getting is 
`java.sql.SQLException: Database 'books' not found.
 at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)...`
Although from ij I see that there is a connection
`ij> show connections;
CONNECTION0* -  jdbc:derby:books
* = current connection`

Comment: If your database is not found, you may need to create it: add `;create=true` to the end of your JDBC Connection URL. Or, maybe you didn't give the correct filesystem path to the location of your DB in your URL. `jdbc:derby:books` just says to look for a DB named 'books' in the CWD, but each process has its own CWD, so the CWD of Eclipse is probably not what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks, interesting fact is that I am able to create(and access) new database, but unable to access prior created(by someone else) database. Could it be administration rights issue?